# How to create a Permission System using Flask (and Flask-login)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, flask-login

I am developing a Web Application using Flask, Flask-Login, and Google App Engine (using NDB as a datastore).

What would be the best way to develop a simple Permission system, allowing you to set up roles and assign them to users, which then subsequently gives them the permission to access certain pages.

Many thanks!

Comment: there's also the [flask-user](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-User/) library, and [stormpath](https://stormpath.com/) is an authentication as a service API.

Comment: Thanks @GG_Python ! Does flask-user work with NDB for Google App Engine? I can only find examples using sql-alchemy at the moment.

Comment: i'm really not sure, but seems from the Flask-User dependency requirements that Flask-SQLalchemy is required, so it may no be particularly compatible with other DBs, not to say that some effort won't get it to work just fine.